# Connecting to Oracle Cloud database from Azure Data Factory using TLS

Tags: oracle, azure, ssl, factory, oracle-adf

I'm trying to connect from Azure Data Factory (linked service) to a free Oracle dB on their cloud service.
It's failing with this error:

*ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Oracle Wire Protocol driver]SSL certificate chain could be built up using the untrusted certificates but the root could not be found locally.*

I've set encryptionmethod=1 and validateservercertificate=false.
The "validateservercertificate" doesn't seem to make any difference.
The host is "adb.uk-cardiff-1.oraclecloud.com", running TLS (not mutual tls).

Does anyone out there know whether it's possible to either get the Azure linked service to trust the certificate, or to get it to not try to validate it in the first place? - this is in an azure hosted AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime, not a self-hosted integration-runtime by the way. I'm only just exploring ADF, so apologies if I'm being a bit slow!

Thanks in advance

Rich

I've tried validateservercertificate=0, and "false", and all available options for encryptionmethod.
validateservercertificate doesn't seem to do anything. encryptionmethod=1 is the only option which even gets that far. Without that, it just drops the connection.